# Copy two dimensional arrays using pointers

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, embedded

I want to copy two dimensional arrays and I made this function but it caused a compilation error

```
void Cpy_2d_arr(unsigned char *from,unsigned char *to)
{
    unsigned char col,row;
    for (row=0;row<4;row++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<4;col++)
        {
            (*(*(to+row)+col)) = (*(*(from+row)+col));
        }
    }

}
```

The two dimensional arrays are
unsigned char arr[4][4] = {'7','8','9','-','4','5','6','*','1','2','3','-','c','0','=','+'};

the target is an array inside a struct with the same size

the errors are :
1- Error 8 expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char (*)[4]
2- Error    11  subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
3- Error    11  invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: If you have a question about a compilation error, you should **always post the error message**.

Comment: Why is this tagged both with objective-c and C?

Comment: Also, this code would a lot simpler to understand if you used `to[row][col]` rather than nested dereferencing.

Comment: Where are the two dimensional arrays? What are their sizes?

Answer (score 0):

```
 char arr[4][4] = {'7','8','9','-','4','5','6','*','1','2','3','-','c','0','=','+'};
```

is an array of pointers

```
void Cpy_2d_arr(unsigned char *from,unsigned char *to)
```

receives an single pointer( e.g. to an array of chars).

the types of your parameters are not compatible, change it to

```
void Cpy_2d_arr(unsigned char from[4][4],unsigned char to[4][4])
```

it should work just fine

Comment: Does this answer your question?